# Swiper не исчезают слайдера

Tags: javascript, swiper

Спасайте плз ._.

Нужно сделать свайпер с изображениями с помощью Swiper js  у меня была 6 версия но там был баг с margin top поэтому сказали перейти на 7 версию. Когда я перешёл на неё вроде все настроил, но слайды не исчезают и появляется нижний скролл.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код:

```js
  new Swiper(".gallery__swiper-container", {
    loop: false,
    slideClass: 'gallery__swiper-slide',
    pagination: {
      el: '.gallery__swiper-pagination',
      type: 'fraction',
    },

    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },

    slidesPerView: 4,
    slidesPerGroup: 6,
    grid: {
      rows: 2,
      fill: "row",
    },
    spaceBetween: 10,
  });
```

Не знаю возможно проблема в HTML?

Comment: slidesPerView: 4 у вас стоит, соответственно, у вас и отображается 4 слайда. Пример реализации данного слайдера есть в кодпене у куратора курса по верстке

Comment: пример есть вот только он не работает

Comment: https://codepen.io/dmitrij-borisenko-the-lessful/pen/XWgNeOR смотрите внимательно)